# How can I add a phone auth provider to a tenant in Identity Platform/Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I can only seem to add the phone auth provider to the default tenant. How can I add it to a tenant? It seems to be missing in the dropdown.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding in my previous response. The phone auth provider cannot be added to a specific tenancy of Firebase's Identity Platform, as I believe you to be trying to accomplish. All tenants have access to the phone auth provider by default; it cannot be added to a particular tenant.

Comment: Since this feature is not yet available. You can file a feature request in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: It doesn't even seem like all tenants have access to it btw. Only the default one.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268476475